# I tried to make a painter in browser, but then it went to making an 'eraser' it didn't work because it doesn't change the color

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the eraser event listener function, I change the line color to the background color. It changes(as I can see by console.log), but in the `canv` event listener function it stays the same. I can't add a sandbox example because it can't read `getContext('2d')`

```js
const canv = document.getElementById('canvas');
const repeat = document.querySelector('.repeat');
const fill = document.querySelector('.fill');
const eraser = document.querySelector('.erase');
const buttons = document.querySelector('.buttons');
let color;
var ctx = canv.getContext('2d');
var isMouseDown = false;
canv.width = 790;
canv.height = 920;

canv.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
  isMouseDown = true;
});
canv.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
  isMouseDown = false;
});

eraser.addEventListener('click', function() {
  color = canv.style.backgroundColor;
  console.log(color);
});
buttons.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  color = e.path[0].name;
});
fill.addEventListener('click', function() {
  canv.style.backgroundColor = color;
});


canv.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  if (isMouseDown) {
    console.log(color);
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.strokeStyle = color;
    ctx.lineTo(e.clientX - 80, e.clientY);
    ctx.lineWidth = 20;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.beginPath(e.clientX - 80, e.clientY);
    ctx.arc(e.clientX - 80, e.clientY, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(e.clientX - 80, e.clientY);
  } else if (!isMouseDown) {
    ctx.beginPath();
  }

});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

button {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 10px 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.colors,
.tools {
  margin: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container {
  width: 50px;
  height: 0px;
  z-index: 10;
}

#canvas {
  margin: -30px 80px;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: black;
}

.black {
  background-color: black;
}

.white {
  background-color: white;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.purple {
  background-color: purple;
}

.erase {
  background: url(img/eraser_PNG18.png) 50%/cover no-repeat;
}

.fill {
  background: url(img/fill.png) 50%/cover no-repeat;
}

.repeat {
  background: url(img/repeat.png) 50%/ cover no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body style="margin: 0;">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="buttons">
      <div class="colors">
        <button name="black" class="black"></button>
        <button name="white" class="white"></button>
        <button name="yellow" class="yellow"></button>
        <button name="green" class="green"></button>
        <button name="blue" class="blue"></button>
        <button name="purple" class="purple"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="tools">
        <button class="fill"></button>
        <button class="erase"></button>
        <button class="repeat"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <canvas id="canvas" style="display: block;">CANVAS ISN'T WORKINGGG</canvas>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried to check if the color changed,but still don't understand why it is at the same time changed in the erase function and didn't change in the canv function

Comment: I can't see where you have set the canv.style.backgroundColor other than on fill.

Answer (score 0):

Just a few fixes, and you're good to go.

1. Set a default background color for your canvas. It can be anything you want - in the fix below, I set it to a grey variant.
2. Change this

```
const buttons = document.querySelector('.buttons');
```

into this

```
const buttons = document.querySelector('.colors');
```

I believe this was just a simple mistype, or something happening because you might have reorganized your `div` elements, and forgotten to change the target in your JS - by using the `.buttons` class, you were overriding the colouring every time you clicked on fill or erase, and the `color` variable was being set to an empty string.

3. Change this

```
color = e.path[0].name;
```

into this

```
color = e.target.name;
```

While this will change your code into something that will work, and actually get the colours from the clicked button's name, it isn't ideal. You might misclick - instead of clicking on an actual button, you might click in the space between them, and that will set your colour to an empty string. Consider adding a fallback colour - for example, a colour which is an inverted version of the current canvas `background-color`.

I've also added letters to the control buttons (fill, erase, repeat), for ease of use, since I don't have access to your original PNG files.

Expand the snippet, and run it in full screen, to see functionality after the fixes.

```js
const canv = document.getElementById('canvas');
const repeat = document.querySelector('.repeat');
const fill = document.querySelector('.fill');
const eraser = document.querySelector('.erase');
const buttons = document.querySelector('.colors');
var color = "";
var ctx = canv.getContext('2d');
var isMouseDown = false;
canv.width = 790;
canv.height = 920;

canv.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
  isMouseDown = true;
});
canv.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
  isMouseDown = false;
});

eraser.addEventListener('click', function() {
  color = canv.style.backgroundColor;
});
buttons.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  color = e.target.name;
});
fill.addEventListener('click', function() {
  canv.style.backgroundColor = color;
});

canv.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  if (isMouseDown) {
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.strokeStyle = color;
    ctx.lineTo(e.clientX - 80, e.clientY);
    ctx.lineWidth = 20;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.beginPath(e.clientX - 80, e.clientY);
    ctx.arc(e.clientX - 80, e.clientY, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(e.clientX - 80, e.clientY);
  } else if (!isMouseDown) {
    ctx.beginPath();
  }

});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

button {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 10px 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.colors,
.tools {
  margin: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container {
  width: 50px;
  height: 0px;
  z-index: 10;
}

#canvas {
  margin: -30px 80px;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: black;
}

.black {
  background-color: black;
}

.white {
  background-color: white;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.purple {
  background-color: purple;
}

.erase {
  background: url(img/eraser_PNG18.png) 50%/cover no-repeat;
}

.fill {
  background: url(img/fill.png) 50%/cover no-repeat;
}

.repeat {
  background: url(img/repeat.png) 50%/ cover no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body style="margin: 0;">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="buttons">
      <div class="colors">
        <button name="black" class="black"></button>
        <button name="white" class="white"></button>
        <button name="yellow" class="yellow"></button>
        <button name="green" class="green"></button>
        <button name="blue" class="blue"></button>
        <button name="purple" class="purple"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="tools">
        <button class="fill">F</button>
        <button class="erase">E</button>
        <button class="repeat">R</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <canvas id="canvas" style="display: block;background-color:#ccc">CANVAS ISN'T WORKINGGG</canvas>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```